# enable and disable functional index in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Am using Functional Index `(SUBSTR(PS.BILL_PROD_SOT_ID, 0, INSTR(PS.BILL_PROD_SOT_ID, '_',-1)-1)))` in my oracle table.

My question is if i **use enable and disable Index**  it takes minimum time then
create and drop index ? Am i right ? If so then,

if suppose am use disable Index and then loading a new data's into the table .After that if am enable the functional index ,it will create the index for all the records or else only the newly inserted record along with old indexed data ?

anyone please Clarify me .

Thanks in advance,

Dhamodharan.A

Comment: Here we have usable and unusable indexes. When it's unusable it will disable for all of data.after loading new data you should rebuild it for all of data.

Comment: @mohsen.b thanks for your response.

I have one more doubt on this.the time taken for usable and unusable indexes is lesser than drop and re create the index ?

because i have 250 millions for data in that table and need to insert 2 million data's every day.

Comment: Your are using Normal Way in these situation (making indexes unusable and rebuild them). that's okay.